# Smooth unhover transition for child element

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have an inline-block image div and a span within a parent link element.
I'm using the image as a custom list bullet.

[image]

I want to animate the list bullet upon hover of the entire link element, which I have achieved using the following selector:

```
a:hover > div.bullet {
    animation: ... ;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

However, no matter what I do I am unable to add the same smooth transition for returning the div to its original position.

Here's a working example:

```css
a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

a .bullet {
  margin-right: 1rem;
  height: 1.2rem;
  width: 1.2rem;
  background-image: url('https://www.pngkey.com/png/full/317-3170031_triangle-clipart-small-orange-pennant.png');
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
}

a:hover > .bullet {
  animation: bob 0.5s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes bob {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0.5rem);
  }
}
```

```html
<a id="action1" href="#">
  <div class="bullet"></div>
  <span>item 1</span>
</a>

<a id="action2" href="#">
  <div class="bullet"></div>
  <span>item 2</span>
</a>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: use this - `a:hover > .bullet { transform: translateX(0.5rem) }` and add `transition: all 0.5s ease;` to `.bullet`.

Comment: @Paulie_D Noted, I'm guessing a lot of the SO posts I've come across with jsfiddle links on them were probably asked before Stack Snippets were implemented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can eliminate the keyframes animation and just set the unhovered `transform` on the `.bullet` element, and the hovered `transform` for the `:hover` class.  Does this fulfill your requirements?

```css
a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

a .bullet {
  margin-right: 1rem;
  height: 1.2rem;
  width: 1.2rem;
  background-image: url('https://www.pngkey.com/png/full/317-3170031_triangle-clipart-small-orange-pennant.png');
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transform: translateX(0)
}

a:hover > .bullet {
  transform: translateX(0.5rem);
}
```

```html
<a id="action1" href="#">
  <div class="bullet"></div>
  <span>item 1</span>
</a>

<a id="action2" href="#">
  <div class="bullet"></div>
  <span>item 2</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that this is what pseudo-elements are for. Just add a ::before element and then animate that element alone on hover.

Do note, never animate `all` elements because that loop over all animatable properties, which can create janky animations if the page is busy with other things, like javascript execution, or other types of animations.

```css
a {
  display: flex;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a.bullet::before {
  content: '';
  margin-right: 1rem;
  height: 1.2rem;
  width: 1.2rem;

  background-image: url('https://www.pngkey.com/png/full/317-3170031_triangle-clipart-small-orange-pennant.png');
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}

a.bullet:hover::before  {
  transform: translateX(0.5rem);
}
```

```html
<a id="action1" class="bullet" href="#">item 1</a>
<a id="action2" class="bullet" href="#">item 2</a>
```

Comment: It does look much cleaner on the html side. Thanks for the `all` tip, very helpful.